Connecting Wall ND Missing Vowels
Just a connecting wall with missing vowels!  Or a cnn ctn gwll.  Just some fun missing vowels categories with very little overlap.  One of the categories has a very specific description I'd like to see.











PHLDL PHG LSN DL
NWH MPSHRJ NSND THDLF DS TNY
NWYR KJT SND
CHT RN DKTK-BM


SNB LTN DJH N MCNR
JC KJY NR-K RSNDG RDNR MSY
LSKJ NSN DT HRDR SFTHL STRK
ST TLSH WK SN DX LV


JHNF LNSB RGHN DTH YM GHT BGNTS
CHCG BR SN DXX
HJNS ND THT MP LFDM
JH NFG RTYN DCR DN CCLRW TRR VVL


SNCTHH DGHG NDT HHLK
MN NSTJ NSN DTHLS TCR SD
JH NTY L RNDDRNDRN
JHNL NNLL NDTH YMGH TB GNTS




There might be an H missing the last one...

Is there an R missing from the second entry in the first row?

Is there a Y missing from the third entry in the first row?

Plus an S in R2C3 - starting to think these may be deliberate... (Though I do wonder if an 'R' in the top right might actually be intended as an 'H'...?)

Goshdarn it I swear I checked.  Your erratas are appreciated. (When I did this on another page, I missed a whole vowel!)  R1C4 is correct.

And an N in R3C3

Group 1:

 Musicians named John and their bands
 John Flansburgh and They Might Be Giants
 John Linnell and They Might Be Giants
 John Tyler and Duran Duran
 John Fogerty and Credence Clearwater Revival

Group 2:

 Movie titles if Indiana Jones were named for another state
 New Hampshire Jones and the Dial of Destiny
 Alaska Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark
 Ohio Jones and the Temple of Doom
 Minnesota Jones and the Lost Crusade

Group 3:

 Football teams and the only Super Bowls they won
 New York Jets and III
 Philadelphia Eagles and LII
 Chicago Bears and XX
 Seattle Seahawks and XLVIII

Group 4:

 "The Fast and the Furious"
 Usain Bolt and John McEnroe
 Sonic the Hedgehog and The Hulk
 Jackee Joyner-Kersee and Gordon Ramsay
 Cheetara and Katie Ka-Boom


And that's the exact name I was looking for for the fourth group.  Good job.

+1 This is exactly the entries and categories I got too, with the exception that I had been trying to fit the animal name into the very last one you list. Might be worth noting though that for your cat 3, it is the only one they ever achieved (to date) :)

@Stiv I updated group 3's note.  My one problem was that I couldn't figure out who KTK-BM was for the longest time.
